# New in Python. Issue with "six module"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a piece of code for Python in Eclipse in Windows 7 and I am receiving an error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\admin\workspace\New\src\test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pylab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 226, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\finance.py", line 21, in <module>
    from matplotlib.dates import date2num
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 119, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\rrule.py", line 18, in <module>
    from six import advance_iterator, integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

My source code is

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from scipy.cluster.vq import *
import pylab
pylab.close()

# generate some random xy points and
# give them some striation so there will be "real" groups.
xy = numpy.random.rand(30,2)
xy[3:8,1] -= .9
xy[22:28,1] += .9

# make some z vlues
z = numpy.sin(xy[:,1]-0.2*xy[:,1])

# whiten them
z = whiten(z)

# let scipy do its magic (k==3 groups)
res, idx = kmeans2(numpy.array(zip(xy[:,0],xy[:,1],z)),3)

# convert groups to rbg 3-tuples.
colors = ([([0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1])[i] for i in idx])

# show sizes and colors. each color belongs in diff cluster.
pylab.scatter(xy[:,0],xy[:,1],s=20*z+9, c=colors)
pylab.savefig('/var/www/tmp/clust.png')
```

I am new to Python and I don't know what the problem could be. 
I am using Python version 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the module `six`, just use `pip install six`

If you don't have pip, you can download the package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/1.7.3#downloads), untar the file, change directory
`cd  six-1.7.3` and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: you download the tar file. Untar it. go with command line inside. and type setup.py install and that's it.. Thanks! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's simple - you don't have [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) installed. Install it, for example with pip:

```
pip install six
```